# Published Gmail Add-On Not Showing on Mobile Gmail App

Tags: gmail, gmail-addons, google-developers-console, gsuite-addons

On the [Google Developers page here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail), it says "G Suite add-ons that extend Gmail do so on both desktop and mobile clients."

[My published add-on linked here](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/smarty/744707349722) is on the Marketplace. It is just extending gmail (I've included my manifest file below). However, my add-on only appears on the web. I can't get it to show up on mobile.

What am I doing wrong or is there a bug? Why is my published Gmail add-on not showing up on the mobile gmail app?

Thank you for all your help!

Manifest File (appscript.json):

```
 {
  "timeZone": "GMT",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Smarty",
    "logoUrl": "https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5e55a48565fc4c78f503ac25/1586923750635-O2EA9H2ZLCH4B926L8T3/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kJK4Mm1kch8SFO9ZNkN1NT97gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QHyNOqBUUEtDDsRWrJLTmN9YSRtfoTLg6dUq-6F17A0FFZK5fArcnK1IqGweyunyWChwIwkIJ_P7MaZif-uMs/SmartyDescriptor.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {
      },
      "onTriggerFunction": "getContextualAddOn"
    }],
    "primaryColor": "#40c2ff",
    "secondaryColor": "#e84f81"
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", 
    "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"
  ],
  "urlFetchWhitelist": [
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.js",
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.28/moment-timezone-with-data.js",
    "https://api.wit.ai/"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Comment: Have you figured it out? I have the same question

Answer (score 2):

just to make sure what is meant by mobile: it is the mobile gmail app (android/iOS) not a mobile web browser. because it is not working in the latter

you need to open an email on your gmail app, scroll to the bottom and click on the addon icon next to the text "Available add-ons", see https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/starting-addons#on_mobile_gmail_only

and currently thats the only way. as there is this restriction that you can only open it from within an email, so there is no homepage or view outside of an email. so there the add-on is simply not available. see https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/starting-addons#on_mobile_gmail_only

that likely may have been why you did not find it